# Нулевой массив, но с элементами

Tags: jquery, ajax

Начну по порядку:
Есть глобальный массив ligues в который я делаю push объекты полученные в функции GetData(). Однако когда я обращаюсь к GetData() в функции FillLiguesMenu(seazon), то данный массив возвращается с объектами, но в виде Arra[0],[image: введите сюда описание изображения] хотя запушенные объекты в нем присутствуют.  в итоге я не могу пройтись по этому массиву в той же  FillLiguesMenu(seazon) - второй цикл for. Перенести функцию FillLiguesMenu(seazon) в GetData() я не хочу, та как я ею буду пользоваться в других частях кода.

```
var country = ['en', 'it', 'de', 'es'];
    var seazons = ['2012-13', '2013-14', '2014-15', '2015-16', '2016-17'];
    var ligues = [];

    function Initialize() {
    FillSezonCombo();
    FillLiguesMenu(seazons[seazons.length - 1]);
}

    function GetData(country, seazon) {
    $.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendatajson/football.json/master/' + seazon + '/'+ country +'.1.clubs.json', function (text, status) {
        data1 = JSON.parse(text);
        console.log(data1);
        currentLigue = new Ligues(data1, country);
        ligues.push(currentLigue);
        console.log(ligues.length);
    });
    $.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/opendatajson/football.json/master/' + seazon + '/' + country + '.1.json', function (text, status) {
        data2 = JSON.parse(text);
        console.log(data2);
    });
}

function FillSezonCombo() {
    var currentSeazon = '2016-17';
    $('.btn-seazon').append('SEAZON ' + currentSeazon + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
    for (var i = 0; i < seazons.length; i++) {
        $('.seazon-items').append('<li class="sz-item"><a href="#">' + seazons[i] + '</a></li>');        
    }
    $('.sz-item').click(function () {
        $('.btn-seazon').empty();
        currentSeazon = $(this).text();
        $('.btn-seazon').append('SEAZON ' + currentSeazon + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
    });
}

function FillLiguesMenu(seazon) {
    for (let i = 0; i < country.length; i++) {
        GetData(country[i], seazon);
    }
    console.log(ligues.length);

    for (let j = 0; j < ligues.length; j++) {
        console.log(ligues[j].country);
        console.log(ligues[j].liguesName);
        $('.ligue').append('<li class="' + ligues[j].country + '">' + ligues[j].liguesName + '</li>');
    }
}

function Ligues(data, country) {
    this.country = country;
    this.liguesName = data.name;
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0)

Comment: Все что я смогу на данном этапе, так это способы 0, на все остальное я пока моих знаний не хватает, однако 0-1 способ мне не подходит.